# Why is the inbox _so small_?

Tags: discussion, usability, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

I mean, apparently "size doesn't matter" but that's besides the point.

[image: small inbox]

If you look at that itty bitty window, and how much information it has, I wonder how often do you expect us to check it?  And *why is it so small*?

Why isn't the inbox available in your "user profile" page?

Why can't you drag-to-expand the window?

Comment: "Why isn't the inbox available in your "user profile" page" - Well, technically it is, just only [on your *network* profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/38717/bobobobo?tab=inbox).

Comment: A bigger box just looks [silly to me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n3pz0.png)

Comment: You did see the "more inbox messages" at the bottom of that list? (To get to the Inbox that Tim showed you?)

Comment: I want a silly box. Why not make it resizable with the mouse, with a memory of the size given by the user ?

Comment: It doesn't look small to me at all, being popup inner window. We shouldn't be looking there all day long just when we get new notification. Adding link in the user profile is possible request, but not sure it has much point.

Comment: Why is your screen so big?  I'll trade you, everybody happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother, when larger version inbox is just a few clicks away - in a network profile.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nDGF.png]

Whenever I need something more than clicking most recent message, I go to that *real* inbox.

Comment: Oh, roflmao, I see it now